# Tag synonyms: toxicity, toxins, toxicology

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I found these tags which should IMO be synonyms of each other or merged together:

- **[toxicity](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toxicity)** (19 questions, 1 follower)

  **Excerpt:** 
  Questions related to being poisonous; relating to or caused by poison(s).

  **Wiki:** *none*
- **[toxins](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toxins)** (6 questions, 0 follower)

  **Excerpt:** *none*

  **Wiki:** *none*
- **[toxicology](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toxicology)** (2 questions, 0 follower)

  **Excerpt:** *none*

  **Wiki:** *none*

Simply looking at their stats, [toxicity](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toxicity) is most popular and should be the master tag.

On the other hand, [Biology.SE has a `toxicology` tag only](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/toxicology/synonyms), so making that one the master tag would make it easier for people coming from there.

Comment: I'd go with toxicology since it is the most comprehensive of the three.

Comment: I think you should use toxicity and toxicology.

Comment: These tags are **not** synonyms.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that they stay separate and that the tag wiki for toxicity should be updated as it is not correct.

> Toxicity: The degree to which a substance (a toxin or poison) can harm humans or animals. Acute toxicity involves harmful effects in an organism through a single or short-term exposure.

The way I see this is it talks more about how much of a substance is required when talking about toxic levels. This is important as normally harmless substances can become toxic as the situation changes. Examples are large quantities of water (and I don't mean drowning) or oxygen at higher pressures. Also if you not the definition of toxin this includes items not in that list.

> Toxins: an antigenic poison or venom of plant or animal origin, especially one produced by or derived from microorganisms and causing disease when present at low concentration in the body.

This is referring specific types of poisons and harmful materials

> Toxicology: the branch of science concerned with the nature, effects, and detection of poisons.

This is referring to the study and is more of a meta tag.

Comment: I am not too familiar with this site yet, but I tend to disagree. While one could theoretically draw some borders between those tags, I think most people will not note the difference - and how many people do read the tag wikis before picking them? And what value would this differentiation add? Somebody following one of those tags would also follow the others, I think there's no difference in the knowledge needed to answer the question.

Comment: @ByteCommander While some people might not recognize the difference, this is a site about health knowledge so we should strive to recognize that there is a difference  and help spread that knowledge.

Comment: @ByteCommander I know the difference and those tags are **not** synonyms. I agree with Joe here that the tags could use some polishing but they should not be merged as synonyms because they are not synonyms. Dumbing down the site is never an answer to anything.